# How to run an android application connected to SQL Server on phone

Tags: android, asp.net, sql-server

I have an Android app in Android Studio. My program connects to SQL Server through an API written with .NET and displays information in recyclerview and has a login page. This program run well on my laptop, because both the desired database and the API and Android Studio are in the same system. This program displays information when the API is running through Visual Studio. I want to run this app on my phone; how can I do that? The API is not in the phone or the database and... the API is on the local host.

In general, how can we run an Android application that is connected to SQL Server on phone?

I pinged the phone to the computer but my laptop and phone are not pinging each other.

I can run the app on the Android Studio emulator, but not the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Allow Remote Connections is enabled on the SQL server.

It is advised to connect to your server with SQL Server Management Studio from another PC for easier troubleshooting.

Comment: I checked the Allow Remote Connections, it is enabled...
Do you mean that I should connect to the phone from another system's SQL?

Comment: No, connect to your server from another PC, that way you can narrow down potential problems.

Comment: I re-read your question now and you have conflicting statements: "..the API is on the local host." and "In general, how can we run an Android application that is connected to SQL Server on phone" - just to be clear, I am answering the second one.